# imagick install problerm:undefined symbol: MagickGetImageBluePrimary in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, webp

Recently i want to add webp support for my imagemagick.

I install libwebp-0.3.1 and imagemagick-6.8 correctly,but after i install imagick-3.0.1 successfully , I run cmd:

`$:php -m | grep "imagick"`

it shows:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: MagickGetImageBluePrimary in Unknown on line 0
```

so i change to imagick-2.3.0,surely it works.But anyone find solution to work with imagick-3.0.1????

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to help the future commands to find MagickWand with the command

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

then config and install imagick-3.0.0 or imagick-3.0.1:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The answer link is here:
http://semigr.livejournal.com/97622.html